# Angular 2 - HTTP basic auth request unable to enter details

Tags: javascript, angular, http, authentication, authorization

I've been trying multiple approaches to accessing an API that uses basic auth. The problem is Angular 2 is unable to enter the username and password.

If you navigate to a basic auth website, it will ask you to put in a username and password and then on most browser you click `Log In` or `Cancel`. If you click cancel on this website it will return a string saying `User pressed Cancel`, and that exactly what I am getting by doing it through Angular's HTTP request.

At this stage it doesn't even matter if the encode username and password in the Authorization header is correct, I just need to be able to send a username and password and have it try to login.

Any suggestions?

```
request() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', "Basic dWRpZDM6cGFzc3dvcmQ=");

        this.http.get('http://localhost:8888/api/', {
            headers: headers
        })
            .subscribe(
                data => this.example = data.text(),
                err => this.logError(err.text()),
                () => console.log('Request Complete')
            );
        console.log(this.example);
    }
```

Comment: Running this code returns `There was an error: User pressed Cancel`, as it is handed to my error handling function.

Comment: Have you tried using `RequestOptions`? For example, `let opts: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
 opts.headers = headers; this.http.get('path', opts)...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually wasn't with Angular 2 or JS at all, the headers were been attached and sent. But Apache was not passing on the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` onto PHP.

To fix this I had to set the following in the `.htaccess` on the API directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

and then I had to manually set the `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW`.

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':', base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
$data = array();
```

The other work around is to create a PHP or Node.js wrapper locally and send the parameters onto that page from angular, and then use that page to make a `CURL` request which also worked.

Answer (score 5):

Adding authorization using username & password should help. Please try following :

```
      let username : string = 'username';
      let password : string = 'password';
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      this.http.get('http://localhost:8888/api/', {
        headers: headers
      }).subscribe(
            data => this.example = data.text(),
            err => this.logError(err.text()),
            () => console.log('Request Complete')
        );
    console.log(this.example);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: btoa(username + ":" + password) turns that string into a base 64 encoded string. My example above is showing that string. I tried your example anyway but no luck!

Comment: have you tried login with postman or some other tool? May be you are missing some header.

Comment: Postman works along with curl request, I think the problem lies with angular being unable to make a pre-flight request.